# Hundreds of filepaths reference to one genuie file

Tags: macos, filesystem

I have one file,to which hundreds of filepaths reference to.

```
In [96]: len(paths_list)
Out[96]: 191
In [97]: paths_list
Out[97]:
['~/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.PressAndHold/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal.CalendarNC/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.languageassetd/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.share.Video.upload-Youku/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.PassKit.PaymentAuthorizationUIExtension/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt',
 ...]
```

They are of the same file.

What's the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 1):

There happens to be symbolic links which puts your ~\Desktop folder in each Data folder. So if you execute the command shown below, the output will contain many printed lines. Most of these lines will show a path through a `Data/Desktop` symbolic link. Note, the `-L` option causes the `find` command to follow symbolic links.

```
find  -L  ~  -name  sample.txt  -print
```

If you execute the command given below, the same output will be produced, minus the lines showing a path through a `Data/Desktop` symbolic link.

```
find  ~  -name  sample.txt  -print
```

The output from the above command should contain at least the following line.

```
/Users/YourUsername/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt
```

A symbolic link is just a file containing a character string. Each directory entry for such files contains a flag indicating the file is a symbolic link. The character string stored in a symbolic link file can be printed by executing the `readlink` command. For example, you could enter the following command, on your computer.

```
readlink  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration/Data/Desktop
```

This would produce the following output.

```
../../../../Desktop
```

So when symbolic links are being followered and the file name

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt
```

is encountered, the `Desktop` string gets replaced by the string `../../../../Desktop` to produce

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration/Data/../../../../Desktop/Dev/sample.txt
```

which is equivalent to the

```
~/Desktop/Dev/sample.txt
```

file name.